# How to make a checkbox group active or innactive when a certain radio button is checked?

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, radio-button

I'm building a form and on a section of it I have two radio buttons with values "No" and "Yes" respectively. Following I have two checkcbox fields. I would like the users to be required to select at least one of the checkbox fields when the YES radio button is selected and to reset the checkbox fields when the radio button No is selected.

I'm trying to write a JavaScript that will do the following:

a) On load all the fields most be active it's required to select one of the radio buttons.

b) If radioGroup1/"No" is selected, reset the values of the checkbox fields and make them nonactive.

b) If radioGroup2/"Yes" is selected make the checkbox fields active and make it required to select at least one.

I haven't got to anywhere yet. Could anyone give me a direction here? Thanks

```
<label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" id="radioGroup1" value="No">No</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" id="radioGroup2" value="Yes">Yes(Year/City)</label>

<div class="checkboxGroup">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup[]" id="checkboxGroup1" value="Value 1">Value 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup[]" id="checkboxGroup2" value="Value 2">Value 2</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's an option for you to use jQuery - if yes, I just made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/x1tysLoc/2/)

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function () {
 if ($(this).val() == "No") {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled",true);
    $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
}
else {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

In case it has to be pure javascript, just drop a comment, that'd just take some minutes more.

Update: As requested a pure Javascript solution:

```
document.getElementById("radioGroup1").onclick = function () {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].checked = false;
    elems[i].disabled = true;
  }
};
document.getElementById("radioGroup2").onclick = function () {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].disabled = false;
  }
};
```

HTML-adjustment for this was to add class="checkbox" for the checkboxes.
Could be adjusted to have a single onclick for the radios calling one function, then to check for the value of the clicked radio button and have the if/else of above jQuery-approach, but just as quick example.

[Fiddle - Javascript-Version](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/x1tysLoc/4/)

Comment: This look good and I'm ok with Jquery. 

I've changed it a bit to work with classes and it made me wonder if I could build a function out of it with the radio buttons and checkbox class as paramethers?  http://jsfiddle.net/vinicius5581/30don0vr/1/

Comment: Sure you can adjust it further, it depends on what you're planning to have as result - e.g. in case you'd like to have multiple checkbox/radiobutton-groups with a similar functionality, it would be possible to call a function to enable/disable the related checkboxes. But in case those check/radio-groups would be grouped in the same way as in the example, it would also be possible just to adjust the current version to enable/disable the closest checkboxes - e.g. like this: $(this).closest("input[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled",true);

Comment: I updated it a bit http://jsfiddle.net/axelduch/30don0vr/4/ is this  what you want ?

Comment: @aduch only thing you should remove is the "checkboxes.prop("checked", true);" as it checks both checkboxes in case yes is clicked

Comment: About that version without Jquery. Would you mind sharing it?

Comment: @ViniciusSantana Np, just written one: http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/x1tysLoc/4/

Comment: Can be adjusted not to be based on single functions for the id of each button but to check for the value and then proceed with the if/else inside the click, but just as a quick example for a pure javascript solution.

Comment: @aduch don't mind, thx for your fiddle as I like that approach, and btw nice flash that you have on your site

Comment: @matthias_h there are too many comments for this answer, but still I appreciate your enthusiasm.